# Remove opacity of a children element

Tags: css, react-native

I'm trying to make an overlay View within opacity, and I would like to remove the opacity on a child element see the picture :

[image]

```
<View style={styles.layer} pointerEvents={"none"}>
    <Component {...props}/>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    layer: {
        opacity: 0.5,
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

I tried to :

- Set the children opacity to 1 : No effect,
- Set rgba values to parent and children with different alpha value:  I lost the opacity on the parent layer

How to handle that

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a child element less transparent than the parent, without some trickery:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/opacity/

Comment: The things its my children component is a reused component i can't make this trick...

Comment: The best solution is to use colors with transparency in the different elements of the parent element using rgba.

Comment: Yes but as mentionned, rgba has no effects on my components...

Answer (score -1):

please change the style of icon and give opacity to 0